# I want to display a report on a web page The report needs a single parameter (prompt, possibly)

Tags: html, report, microstrategy

I want to display a Microstrategy report on a web page The report needs a single parameter

I have a report that has a (local) filter which I'd like to able to parameterize.   Not the whole filter string but just the numeric value that the report filters on.

I know that I can use a prompt to put a value into a report, but I need to do this from an HTML document which, I understand, can't be done with a prompt.

Is there another way to do pass a parameter from an HTML document into the filter of report in the HTML document?

Kind Regards,
Barrie

Comment: Are you using a server-side programming language to generate the report?

Comment: Strictly speaking, I'm using Oracle SQL but in actuality I'm using the Microstrategy report editor to develop the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a URL to the report, you can pass a prompt answer in as a parameter, specifically `valuePromptAnswers`.

TN15734 on the MicroStrategy Knowledgebase gives a full example, if that isn't clear enough.